# java.lang.VerifyError: org/primefaces/behavior/confirm/ConfirmBehaviorHandler Wrong return type in function

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

This morning (South African time), Maven downloaded the latest primefaces jar (version 5.3). While my project is setup in a manner that maven deploys the project to my Web Container (in this case, Wildfly 9.0.1.Final), it failed deployment due to the following exception:

```
2015-10-19 09:52:36,696 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/primefaces/behavior/confirm/ConfirmBehaviorHandler, method: createBehavior signature: (Ljavax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/primefaces/behavior/base/AbstractBehavior;) Wrong return type in function
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:420)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processBehavior(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:374)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:441)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

2015-10-19 09:52:36,702 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vldm-admin: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vldm-admin: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/primefaces/behavior/confirm/ConfirmBehaviorHandler, method: createBehavior signature: (Ljavax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/primefaces/behavior/base/AbstractBehavior;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/primefaces/behavior/confirm/ConfirmBehaviorHandler, method: createBehavior signature: (Ljavax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/primefaces/behavior/base/AbstractBehavior;) Wrong return type in function
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:224)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/primefaces/behavior/confirm/ConfirmBehaviorHandler, method: createBehavior signature: (Ljavax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/primefaces/behavior/base/AbstractBehavior;) Wrong return type in function
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/primefaces/behavior/confirm/ConfirmBehaviorHandler, method: createBehavior signature: (Ljavax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/primefaces/behavior/base/AbstractBehavior;) Wrong return type in function
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:420)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processBehavior(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:374)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:441)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    ... 10 more
```

I have reverted back to PrimeFaces 5.2 for now do get the application up and running.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I saw the posts already. I thought those issues were fixed because I don't get this issue in version 5.2 but it happens on 5.3. There must be a configuration file issue when they build in different environments (my guess).

Answer (score 16):

I had the exact same error message. The problem was that there still was the old `primefaces-5.2.jar` in my WAR (pulled in by Maven in my case). After cleaning the whole project the problem was gone.

So make sure that there is no older version of Primefaces hidden somewhere in your project or deployment.

Comment: I had done Maven clean and clean-verify and it only had the `primefaces-5.3.jar` in my WAR file only. I think it's more than that.

Comment: Did you search in your file-system for primefaces-5.2.jar (or whatever older version you may have used)?

Comment: I did. It's only on my maven `.m2` folder, which is expected but it used Primefaces 5.3 jar. I even cleaned Wildfly and did a brand new build and still the same error. I will retry again tonight to see if the issue still persists as I am on a tight deadline.

Comment: If you also use Maven please look at Maven's output and search it for Primefaces to see which versions are pulled.

Comment: Had both primefaces-5.2.jar and 5.3 in same dependencies. Removed 5.2 and it worked!

Comment: Thank you Bob.  Doing a Shift-F11 (clean and build) in Netbeans solved the problem.

Comment: just wanna add that I cleaned out IntelliJ, and the error still remained; I then manually went through the output folders and found the 5.2 JAR there; worked perfectly afterwards

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed the culprit but it is not necessarily a Primefaces 5.2/5.3 issue; I accidentally had both a community 5.2 release and an elite 5.2.14 release deployed at the same time and got this exact error. Removing the community release solved the problem. Its more of a "don't have primefaces twice" kind of deal.

Answer (score 0):

You must clean the logs, data and tmp folders on Wildfly. Additionally, you must verify in your WEB-INF/lib folder and erase all the libraries related to primefaces. Finally, run other time the Maven on the project.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
in eclipse in "servers" tab right-click on the Tomcat instance and click on "**Clean Tomcat Work Directory ...**".

Comment: As I said on my post, I am running RedHat Wildfly 9.0.1.Final application server and **not** Tomcat.

Comment: Have you try it with your wildfly? If you use eclipse you can try it anyway even with wildfly. I suppose it's behaviour of eclipse - wrong handling of libraries for the server instance.

Comment: It's not an Eclipse behaviour as my maven `pom.xml` build configuration points to a Wildfly AS. There is no relationship with Eclipse here.